# Trying to generate email from data in Excel spreadsheet, getting compile error "User defined type not defined"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to generate an email from data input on to a spreadsheet, to create an offer of work. But when I do, I keep getting the same error: Compile error, user-defined type not defined

I've gone into "Tools" > References and ticked the "Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library" checkbox, but I get the same error. When I'm trying to search for other answers on this subject, this seems to be the solution for most.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Generate_offer()

Dim strFile As String
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem

  Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set objOutlookMsg = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

  With objOutlookMsg
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
    .To = ""
    .Subject = "xxxxxxxx"
    .Body = "Dear " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "xxxxxxxx" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
    & "xxxxxxxx" & vbNewLine _
    & "xxxxxxxx" & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "C").Value & vbNewLine _
    & "xxxxxxxx" & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "J").Value & " - " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "K").Value & vbNewLine _
    & "xxxxxxxx" & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "M").Value & "xxxxxxxx" & vbNewLine _
    & "Notes: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
    & "xxxxxxxx" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
    & "xxxxxxxx" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "xxxxxxxx" 
    .display
  End With

  'objOutlookMsg.Send
  Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What line is the error on. When I try this it works fine when reference to MS outlook 16.0 Object Library is ticked. And please show a small screencapture of your ticked references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get no errors when changing your Dim to Objects

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Generate_offer()

Dim strFile As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim objOutlookMsg As Object

  Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set objOutlookMsg = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

  With objOutlookMsg
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
    .To = ""
    .Subject = "xxxxxxxx"
    .Body = "Dear " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "xxxxxxxx" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
    & "xxxxxxxx" & vbNewLine _
    & "xxxxxxxx" & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "C").Value & vbNewLine _
    & "xxxxxxxx" & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "J").Value & " - " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "K").Value & vbNewLine _
    & "xxxxxxxx" & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "M").Value & "xxxxxxxx" & vbNewLine _
    & "Notes: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
    & "xxxxxxxx" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
    & "xxxxxxxx" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "xxxxxxxx"
    .display
  End With

  'objOutlookMsg.Send
  Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is using 'Early Binding'.. where in order to use `Dim Something As Outlook.Something`, Excel needs to have the Outlook Library referenced.

You have two options.

You can rectify this by either

**Adding the reference** - 
In the VB Editor window, ensuring the code execution is halted entirely, go to Tools > References and tick Microsoft Outlook x.x Object Library (x.x will depend on the version you have installed).

**Or use late binding** - which keeps the declarations open (as objects) that get bound as you use them:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Generate_offer()

    Dim strFile As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim objOutlookMsg As Object

    Dim olMailItem As Long

    olMailItem = 0 ' (0 = Mail item, 1 = Appointment, 2 = Contact etc..)

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objOutlookMsg = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With objOutlookMsg
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
        .To = ""
        .Subject = "xxxxxxxx"
        .Body = "Dear " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "xxxxxxxx" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
        & "xxxxxxxx" & vbNewLine _
        & "xxxxxxxx" & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "C").Value & vbNewLine _
        & "xxxxxxxx" & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "J").Value & " - " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "K").Value & vbNewLine _
        & "xxxxxxxx" & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "M").Value & "xxxxxxxx" & vbNewLine _
        & "Notes: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
        & "xxxxxxxx" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
        & "xxxxxxxx" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "xxxxxxxx"
        .display
    End With

    'objOutlookMsg.Send
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

Note - the main reason I'd use Late Binding would be if the macro is going to be used on multiple machines with different Excel versions installed. If Early Binding is used and the reference is pointing at a specific version that isn't installed, you'll get an error. Late Binding will find any version that provides Outlook.

Comment: One draw back with `Late Binding` is that you don't get **intellisense**. But there are ways round it.. i.e. you could just use `Early Binding` when you are in dev

Comment: Agreed, I should've more clearly stated Early Binding is generally considered preferable.